# Angular Material - Paginate dynamic table

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, angular-material, angular11

I have a dynamic table in Angular Material, where I collect the data using an API from an external database. I'm trying to paginate the table but I only find examples of tables with predefined data and I can't adopt it.

I have added my HTML and my current .ts in which the only thing I do is show the data in a table, in the HTML I have added the mat-paginator tag to show it but I don't know how to make it work in the .ts.

This is my component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ClientService } from '../../services/clients.service';
import { Client } from '../../domain/clients';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['name'];
  public client: Client;
  public clients: Client[];

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private clienteService: ClienteService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClients();
  }

  getClientes() {
    this.clienteService.list()
    .subscribe(client => this.clientes = client);
  }

}
```

This is my component.html:

```
<div class="title">Customers</div>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" class="m-3">
  <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="clients">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients; let i = index">
          <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" [appearance]="editIndex != i ? 'none' : 'legacy'">
            <input matInput placeholder="{{clients.name}}" [(ngModel)]="clients.name" [readonly]="editIndex!=i">
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let col; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `MatTableDataSource` as the datasource, it contains the `paginator` property for table pagination.

### SOLUTION

> .component.html

```html
<mat-table [dataSource]="this.dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let client; let i = index">
          <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" [appearance]="editIndex != i ? 'none' : 'legacy'">
            <input matInput placeholder="{{client.name}}" [(ngModel)]="client.name" [readonly]="editIndex!=i">
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let col; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    
</mat-table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

> .component.ts

```
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Client>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ...

  getClients() {
    this.clienteService.list().subscribe(client => {
      this.clients = client;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.clients);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
}
```

[Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vtqa38)

---

### RECOMMENDATION(S)

```html
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never" [appearance]="editIndex != i ? 'none' : 'legacy'">
    <input matInput placeholder="{{client.name}}" [(ngModel)]="client.name" [readonly]="editIndex!=i">
</mat-form-field>
```

For `[appearance]`, you should review it and make sure to pass the supported value for MatFormFieldAppearance as listed in [Angular documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormFieldAppearance).

```
type MatFormFieldAppearance = 'legacy' | 'standard' | 'fill' | 'outline';
```

You will get the error as below if you **didn't turn off strict mode for Angular compiler in tsconfig.json**.

> Type '"none"' is not assignable to type 'MatFormFieldAppearance'.

For this scenario, I commented JSON for `angularCompilerOptions` to solve mentioned concern.

> tsconfig.json

```json
{
  ...
},
// "angularCompilerOptions": {
//   "enableIvy": true,
//   "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
//   "strictInjectionParameters": true
// }
```